# Are members of structs in a vector initialized with zero in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

In C++, when I have a struct like

```
struct myStruct
{
  int i;
  bool b;
  MyClass *myobj;
};
```

and I then make a vector of this

```
std::vector<myStruct> myVector;
```

and I resize the vector with

```
myVector.resize(10);
```

Will the struct's members be initialized with zero's (including the pointer)? Can I not assume that and might there be random data in the struct's members?

Comment: Note there is no difference between a class and a struct in this case as it is in other languages e.g. C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this particular case, the answer is **YES** because of [`std::vector::resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)'s properties:

```
If the current size is less than count, additional elements are appended and initialized with copies of value.      (until C++11)

If the current size is less than count,  (since C++11)
    1) additional value-initialized elements are appended
    2) additional copies of value are appended
```

The answer will be **NO** for normal cases, e.g. `myStruct s`, this will leave them (`s.i, s.bool, s.myobj`) with **indeterminate values**.

If you still want them to be initialized as expected, create a constructor for the struct:

```
struct myStruct {
    int i;
    bool b;
    MyClass *myobj;

    myStruct():i(0),b(false),myobj(NULL) { }  // <- set them here by default
};
```

Comment: That cppreference quote is an oversimplification. The actual initialization semantics depends on the definition of the allocator's `construct()`. Also, uninitialized objects have *indeterminate* values, not unspecified ones.

Answer (score 4):

I actually beg to differ. **In this particular case**, the standard appears to guarantee that the objects will be zero-initialized. (All standard references below are to N3936.)

`vector::resize` in this case is specified to append 10 "default-inserted elements to the sequence" (§23.3.6.3 [vector.capacity]/p12).

Default-insertion is in turn defined as (§23.2.1 [container.requirements.general]/p14; `X` is the container's type; `m` is an lvalue of type `A`, which is the container's `allocator_type`):

> An element of `X` is default-inserted if it is initialized by evaluation
>   of the expression
>
> ```
> allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p)
> ```
>
> where `p` is the address of the uninitialized storage for the element allocated within `X`.

Since as written the code uses the default allocator, the `allocator_traits::construct` call simply calls `construct(p)` on an instance of `std::allocator<myStruct>` (§20.7.8.2 [allocator.traits.members]/p5), which is specified as (§20.7.9.1 [allocator.members]/p12)

> ```
> template <class U, class... Args>
> void construct(U* p, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> 12 *Effects*: `::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

Since the parameter pack is empty for `construct(p)`, the effect of the `construct()` call is`::new((void *)p) myStruct()`.

The standard provides that *new-initializers*, like the `()` in the placement new expression above, are to be interpreted "according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct initialization" (§5.3.4 [expr.new]/p17). In turn, §8.5 [dcl.init]/p11 specifies that "An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., `()`, shall be value-initialized."

Value-initialization is specified as (§8.5 [dcl.init]/p8)

> To value-initialize an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a default constructor that is
>     user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default 
>     constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for
>     default-initialization are checked, and if T has a non-trivial default
>     constructor, the object is default-initialized;
> - if `T` is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

In this case, `myStruct` is a "class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor", which means it matches the second bullet point, which performs zero-initialization. Thus, value-initialization for an object of type `myStruct` means the object will be zero-initialized.

However, note that the rules here are quite convoluted, and the path to automatic zero-initialization is quite fragile. For example, if you give `myStruct` a default constructor like `myStruct() { }`, then that's a user-provided default constructor, which means that it will match the first bullet point for value initialization instead of the second, which in turn means that it won't be zero-initialized. Moreover, this may also not work if your `vector` uses a custom allocator, as its `construct()` might have different semantics than that of the default allocator.

Therefore, it is probably better to give `myStruct` a default constructor that explicitly zeroes its members.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the structs will be initialised to zero IN THIS PARTICULAR CASE. The reason is the implementation of the `resize()` method in the STL. New elements are default-constructed:

```
void resize(size_type __new_size) {
    resize(__new_size, value_type());
}
```

`value_type()` results in zero initialisation.

### test evidence

```
#include <cstdio>

struct foo {
  int i;
  int j;
  void *k;
};

void test(const foo& fooinst) {
  printf("%d\n",fooinst.i);
}

main() {
  test(foo());
}
```

Here's the relevant part of the resulting g++ disassembly. Note the explicit zero initialisation of the struct members before the call.

```
test.cpp      ****   test(foo());
  56                            .loc 1 14 0
  57 002d C745F000              movl    $0, -16(%rbp)
  57      000000
  58 0034 C745F400              movl    $0, -12(%rbp)
  58      000000
  59 003b 48C745F8              movq    $0, -8(%rbp)
  59      00000000 
  60 0043 488D45F0              leaq    -16(%rbp), %rax
  61 0047 4889C7                movq    %rax, %rdi
  62 004a E8000000              call    _Z4testRK3foo
```

Answer (score 1):

The values in the `vector` are initialised with the default constructor (or value initialised) of the `struct`, in this case `myStruct`.

The `struct` has no default constructor, so the compiler generated one will be used. In this case it leaves the objects of `myStruct` uninitialised.

No, in general, you cannot assume the data will be zero initialised.

This particular case (the `.resize()`) is picking at a situation where there is value initialisation and there has been some change from C++03 and C++11 (other answers provide more detail).

**Best advice remains**, thing to do is add the default constructor that initialises the `struct` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The ctor for the struct is called.  Since you don't specify one (and you can, even for a struct), a default, do-nothing ctor is used.  The default ctor does not clear the members.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect for `std::vector`s initialization behavior. (See accepted answer)